# How do I get an associated entity's transform?

Tags: rust, specs, amethyst

Imagine I've crated an entity with transform:

```rust
let entity = world.create_entity().with(Transform::default());
```

How do I get its transform later having entity instance? E.g. (pseudo code):

```rust
let transform = entity.get_associated::<Transform>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked for me:

```rust
let transform = world.read_storage::<Transform>().get(entity);
```

It also can be `write_storage`.